# non-loopback access denied error while configuring Spring websocket with rabbitmq

Tags: java, spring-websocket

I am building a Spring Websocket application that user RabbitMQ as message broker.

The configuration file is provided below

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic")
            .setRelayHost("192.168.1.8")
            .setRelayPort(61613)
            .setClientLogin("user")
            .setClientPasscode("user");

    //config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();   
}
}
```

But when I am running the application it gives me the following error

```
Received ERROR {message=[Bad CONNECT], content-type=[text/plain], version=[1.0,1.1,1.2], 
content-length=[26]} session=_system_ text/plain payload=non-loopback access denied
```

I have tried to give the required permissions in rabbitmq

```
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / user ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

But still the problem appears. But the application works fine if I replace the ipaddress in 'setRelayHost(..)' with either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'.

Comment: did you get this issue resolved?

Comment: I also have this same issue

Answer (score 2):

RabbitMQ allows you to configure users to only be able to connect over a loopback interface (localhost), that's also the case of the default user. Check if your user is configured under the `loopback_users` property in the config file or if this is the default user.

Please also check https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

Comment: add following line into config file:
loopback_users.monitoring = true
where monitoring is a custom user

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and after 2 hours of searching I could solved it.
First of all I should bring some codes from `StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler` here:

```
@Override
protected void startInternal() {
    if (this.tcpClient == null) {
        StompDecoder decoder = new StompDecoder();
        decoder.setHeaderInitializer(getHeaderInitializer());
        Reactor2StompCodec codec = new Reactor2StompCodec(new StompEncoder(), decoder);
        this.tcpClient = new StompTcpClientFactory().create(this.relayHost, this.relayPort, codec);
    }

    if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
        logger.info("Connecting \"system\" session to " + this.relayHost + ":" + this.relayPort);
    }

    StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.create(StompCommand.CONNECT);
    accessor.setAcceptVersion("1.1,1.2");
    accessor.setLogin(this.systemLogin);
    accessor.setPasscode(this.systemPasscode);
    accessor.setHeartbeat(this.systemHeartbeatSendInterval, this.systemHeartbeatReceiveInterval);
    accessor.setHost(getVirtualHost());
    accessor.setSessionId(SYSTEM_SESSION_ID);
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Forwarding " + accessor.getShortLogMessage(EMPTY_PAYLOAD));
    }

    SystemStompConnectionHandler handler = new SystemStompConnectionHandler(accessor);
    this.connectionHandlers.put(handler.getSessionId(), handler);

    this.stats.incrementConnectCount();
    this.tcpClient.connect(handler, new FixedIntervalReconnectStrategy(5000));
}
```

So as you see in these lines :

```
accessor.setLogin(this.systemLogin);
accessor.setPasscode(this.systemPasscode);
```

it uses `systemLogin` and `systemPasscode` to login into rabbitmq server.
The default values for these parameters is "*guest*" which is defined at the top of the class:

```
private String systemLogin = "guest";

private String systemPasscode = "guest";
```

With "*guest*" user you can just login to system in **localhost**.

So you should set these parameters in the configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic")
            .setRelayHost("192.168.1.8")
            .setRelayPort(61613)
            .setClientLogin("user")
            .setClientPasscode("user")
            .setSystemLogin("user")
            .setSystemPasscode("user");

    //config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();   
}
}
```

After this configuration if you run this command:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / user ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

every thing goes well.

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the difference between client account and system account, and why do we need to set system account to the same user as client account?
From the StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler we see that the stomp accessor is initialized to system account in startInternal method, and in handleMessageInternal method another copy of stomp accessor is set to client account. But how both methods are used remains unclear. Thank you for you idea and time

Comment: I tried what you suggested. And it did not help